# How can I allow a user to click, dblclick but not select on text in a table with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I understand I can use the ng-click, and ng-dblclick together to capture the click (it will just highlight a row by changing background color), double-click (it will open a modal box with data from that row). But what if I want the user to be able to:

- click on a row
- double-click on a row
- click and edit `<input>` elements if in a `<td>`
- not select text in a table that's not in an input as would normally happen with a double-click.

There's the user-select property but from what I read that's not (and never will be in the CSS spec). So are there any alternatives that I could use.

Comment: I've recently started to use ngGrid and by default, it doesn't enableHighlighting, thus no text selection.  Sounds like you're talking about a table and thought this might give you another approach to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

What I may suggest to create a directive and in the  linking function of the directive have event handler based on what all event you want to bind.

Thanks
Asutosh

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I would have used the user-select property for that. That's true it is non-standard.
Here is some more informations about copy preventions

- [part 1](http://blog.slaks.net/2010/12/on-copy-prevention-in-html-part-1.html)
- [part 2](http://blog.slaks.net/2010/12/on-copy-prevention-in-html-part-2.html)
- [part 3](http://blog.slaks.net/2010/12/on-copy-prevention-in-html-part-3.html)